# Is there a way to show jmeter load details in Dashboard

Tags: jmeter, dashboard, jmeter-5.0

I want to print to dashboard report the loading details.
In case of Thread Group:
threads: 100
ramp up: 10
loop: 1
In case of Ultimate Thread Group: the Threads Schedule details
Is there a way to add them to the report?

Dotan

Answer (score 0):

You can rename the JMeter's dashboard to reflect your load pattern, the [relevant property is `jmeter.reportgenerator.report_title`](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#reporting) so if you do something like:

```
jmeter -Jjmeter.reportgenerator.report_title="threads: 100 ramp up: 10 loop: 1" -n -t test.jmx -f -l result.jtl -e -o dashboard
```

the dashboard title will be changed to the property value:

[image]

More information:

- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://Apache%20JMeter%20Properties%20Customization%20Guide)

Comment: I use the report title for script name. 
I want to add the load details dynamically by code to the report, is there a way to do it?